# what is the Sites on the base site collection of SharePoint online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, site-collection

when I created a Sharepoint site collection on the root. it comes out as

```
https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/**sites**
```

- What are this Sites means?
- Is it possible to create a site's collection without having Sites in the URL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Sites/** is a **Wildcard Managed Paths** which specify that one or more site collections exist at a specified path!

**There are two types of managed paths that you can create:**

- A `wildcard inclusion` allows you to append multiple site collections to the path that you specify.

> For example, if you add /engineering as a wildcard inclusion off of
>   your root site of http://contoso, then you'll be able to create
>   multiple site collections off of http://contoso/engineering.

- An `explicit inclusion` allows you to create a single site collection with the specified address.

> For example, if you add /finance as an explicit inclusion off of your
>   root site of http://contoso, then you'll be able to create a single
>   site collection with the address http://contoso/finance.

For more details check [Managed Paths in SharePoint](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261845(v=office.16).aspx)

---

**Is it possible to create a site's collection without having Sites in the URL ?**

**Unfortunately**, you **can't** create/control `Managed Paths` in SharePoint Online. but you can only manage it in SharePoint On-Premises

Comment: i created a team site and a cummnunication site bouth shows under this "Sites" i couldnt delete the above sites when i tried to go to https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites . how do i remove it ?

Comment: @Rinu As I mentioned above, you can't control (remove .create) managed path in SharePoint online!

Comment: this is kind of confusing for me may be i am not so knowledgeable on the subject. why does wild card has to be there ? why cant we create as much sites collection in the root as we like ?

Comment: @Rinu As you know, the Sharepoint Online is limited feature compared to SharePoint On-prem, one of these limited features is Managed Path that unfortunately,  you can't manage it in SharePoint Online yet! also, you can check this discussion at Microsoft Community that discuss the same topic and wondering like you :) https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint/Managed-Paths-in-SharePoint-Online/td-p/31140

Comment: @Rinu Sure.  - the benefit of wildcards is allowing you to append multiple site collections to the path that you specify like **sites/** and **team/**! Actually,  the benefit of anything depends on your need, now you need to remove it so you feel there is no benefit from it :) but if you would like to create multiple site collections for a specific path , so in this case, you will feel it's useful :) - Please don't hesitate to ask if you need further clarification!